# delete record from mysql, only if Select count return > 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently learning PHP+mysql. I have an AJAX web page. My DB mysql has table grand_score_master.

```
    autoid  user_id package_id  grand_level timestamp   timestring
```

I want to delete all matching records for a user_id, IF that exists in this table. Currently I have to make 2 ajax calls to server, 1st to get count for user_id='ABCD' then if count is > 0, i call another PHP page to run `DELETE from grand_score_master where user_id = 'abcd'`

2 calls are requred because if there are no matching rows in DB, I do not want to fire second call and tell my web page that no record to delete.

Is there any easy way in PHP+mysql to merge these 2 calls in single AJAX call, which return "0 rows" if no matching row exist and "delete successfully" if record matched and rows deleted.

Thanks

Comment: you can use directly delete query. And get return how much you have delete.

Comment: I don't see any problem with just calling `DELETE`, which should return how many records were affected.  No need for two separate AJAX calls.

Comment: like this: `$mysqli->query("DELETE from grand_score_master where user_id = 'abcd'");
printf("Affected rows (DELETE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);`

Comment: mysqli->affected_rows i will use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call first ajax for getting the count followed by second for deleting the record

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: {key: 'value'},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){

           // check the count here in if condition then call another ajax

            // call next ajax function
            $.ajax({ xxx });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thats what i am doing now.

Comment: So instead of have two ajax call write the code in your controller if the count is >0 then delete the record instead of calling it twice

Comment: I will try that. Thanks